# Grails Deployed on Openshift But showing service unavailable (503)

Tags: grails, openshift

Deployed a grails app successfully on openshift. As the log doesnt show any error. But the page I am getting is still 503.

Please help.

My Log is :

```
Apr 30, 2014 8:58:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClusterRuleSetFactory getClusterRuleSet
INFO: Unable to find a cluster rule set in the classpath. Will load the default rule set.
Apr 30, 2014 8:58:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClusterRuleSetFactory getClusterRuleSet
INFO: Unable to find a cluster rule set in the classpath. Will load the default rule set.
Apr 30, 2014 8:59:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 30, 2014 8:59:02 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.5.178.1-8080
Apr 30, 2014 8:59:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5493 ms
Apr 30, 2014 8:59:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 30, 2014 8:59:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Apr 30, 2014 8:59:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT.war
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI
Apr 30, 2014 9:04:42 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.5.178.1-8080
Apr 30, 2014 9:04:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 340606 ms
```

Comment: Is this a scalable app or non-scalable application? Does this work locally? What happens when you restart the application?

Comment: It is a scalable application. It works locally. Earlier nothing was happening when i was restarting app. However I have found the answer and updated the same.

Answer (score 0):

Got It !!!

It was haproxy at the end. after a day of headscratching I got it when I sat with a cooler mind and thought through everything.

This is the link for dealing with 503 error.

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-host-your-java-ee-application-with-auto-scaling

I did not use rhc to connect to haproxy conf though. I used putty.

Comment: Great to know that my blog helped you.